# How does Android NFC contactless payment work?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm studying Android NFC contactless payments.
I'm curious about the 'pay with currently open app' feature in the NFC settings.

My guess is that if I turn off 'pay with currently open app', the default selected app will take the nfc signal even if the currently open app is working with HCE.

I'm curious how this works in the background, but there's no information about it in Android Deployers. If anyone knows anything about this feature, please share.